# Search for files on your computer

Tags: code-challenge

## Task

Write some code that will walk through the entire file-system tree and collect details from file-names, folder-names, text files etc to form a tag-group. This tag group, when searched in (user input) should point to the folders they are located in.

## Rules

1. Any Language (standard libraries only).
2. Any kind of output (should be legible).
3. You may extend your code by reading more file-types and their metadata.
4. Regex is allowed

## You'll win

1. +14 points for the shortest code (will be taken away when some else beats the record)
2. +6 for each added functionality (anything you could possibly claim).
3. -2 for each byte exceeding 1024 byte mark.

## Example

```
Python (using os module - os.walk)
```

input

```
Enter search term below
>>> *camp*
```

output

```
Total results for *camp* = 2
-------------------------------
Camping.avi       - "C:\Users\Amelia\Videos\Summer Camping"
Campus party.avi  - "C:\Users\Public\Campus"
```

Comment: In my neighborhood, "tagging" means something very different.  Anybody know how to get sharpie off my monitor?  Thanks.

Comment: @boothby Sharpie? 'Round here we use spray-paint.

Comment: @Iszi The rattle can's in my backpack, in the other room, but my sharpie was in my pocket.

Answer (score 14):

### BASH, 14 + 6*18 = 122

Cheap, but a win.

```
locate
```

Example:

```
boothby@not ~ $ locate camp
/home/boothby/Desktop/kodak/Pictures/camp.jpg
/home/boothby/Desktop/kodak/Pictures/camp2.jpg
/home/boothby/Downloads/sage-5.12/local/share/doc/networkx-1.7.dev_20131124172629/examples/graph/napoleon_russian_campaign.py
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19/arch/arm/plat-samsung/include/plat/camport.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33/arch/arm/plat-samsung/include/plat/camport.h
```

Feature: this is super efficient since it caches the file information in a database.  The above runs on my computer in 0.187s.

... and 17 additional features:

```
   -b, --basename
          Match only the base name against the specified  patterns.   This
          is the opposite of --wholename.


   -c, --count
          Instead of writing file names on standard output, write the num‐
          ber of matching entries only.


   -d, --database DBPATH
          Replace the default database with DBPATH.  DBPATH is  a  :-sepa‐
          rated  list of database file names.  If more than one --database
          option is specified, the resulting path is  a  concatenation  of
          the separate paths.

          An empty database file name is replaced by the default database.
          A database file name - refers to the standard input.  Note  that
          a database can be read from the standard input only once.


   -e, --existing
          Print  only  entries  that  refer  to files existing at the time
          locate is run.


   -L, --follow
          When checking whether files exist (if the --existing  option  is
          specified),  follow trailing symbolic links.  This causes broken
          symbolic links to be omitted from the output.

          This is the default behavior.  The  opposite  can  be  specified
          using --nofollow.


   -h, --help
          Write  a summary of the available options to standard output and
          exit successfully.


   -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore case distinctions when matching patterns.


   -l, --limit, -n LIMIT
          Exit successfully after finding LIMIT entries.  If  the  --count
          option  is  specified,  the  resulting  count is also limited to
          LIMIT.


   -m, --mmap
          Ignored, for compatibility with BSD and GNU locate.


   -P, --nofollow, -H
          When checking whether files exist (if the --existing  option  is
          specified),  do not follow trailing symbolic links.  This causes
          broken symbolic links to be reported like other files.

          This is the opposite of --follow.


   -0, --null
          Separate the entries on output using  the  ASCII  NUL  character
          instead  of  writing each entry on a separate line.  This option
          is designed for interoperability with the --null option  of  GNU
          xargs(1).


   -S, --statistics
          Write  statistics  about  each  read database to standard output
          instead of searching for files and exit successfully.


   -q, --quiet
          Write no messages about errors  encountered  while  reading  and
          processing databases.


   -r, --regexp REGEXP
          Search  for  a  basic regexp REGEXP.  No PATTERNs are allowed if
          this option is used, but this option can be  specified  multiple
          times.


   --regex
          Interpret all PATTERNs as extended regexps.


   -V, --version
          Write  information  about  the  version and license of locate on
          standard output and exit successfully.


   -w, --wholename
          Match only the whole path name against the specified patterns.

          This is the default behavior.  The  opposite  can  be  specified
          using --basename.
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Right there at the top: `locate`

Comment: That right there is validation to a code-golfer: the solution was so small, an observer couldn't even find it.

Answer (score 5):

BASH

```
find
```

A cheaper, *shorter* win. See @boothby answer for examples

Comment: Bash has always been better. :P

Comment: `find` is shorter, but `locate` is quicker - reminds me of my car navigation system :D

Answer (score 2):

**C# - 200**

```
void G(string s){foreach (var y in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\").Where(k => k.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())))foreach (var f in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\")){Console.WriteLine(y);try{G(f);}catch{}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy (59)

```groovy
a={b-> new File("c:\\").traverse(nameFilter: ~b){print it}}
```

Call it with

```groovy
a('test')
```